# When building a pebble app I'm getting a error I can't understand

Tags: c, json, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am trying to build my pebble app from the SDK for the mac and it keeps giving me the error below. The code itself complies in cloud pebble but for some reason gives me this error that I can't understand.

```
Setting top to                           : 

/Users/PJ/Documents/GitHub/simple-for-pebble 
Setting out to                           : /Users/PJ/Documents/GitHub/simple-for-pebble/build 
Checking for program gcc,cc              : arm-none-eabi-gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : arm-none-eabi-ar 
Found Pebble SDK in          : /Users/PJ/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.8.1/Pebble
'configure' finished successfully (0.082s)
Waf: Entering directory `/Users/PJ/Documents/GitHub/simple-for-pebble/build'
[ 1/15] appinfo.auto.c: appinfo.json -> build/appinfo.auto.c
[ 2/15] Arvo-Bold.ttf.TIME_45.pfo: resources/fonts/Arvo-Bold.ttf ../../../pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.8.1/Pebble/tools/font/fontgen.py -> build/resources/fonts/Arvo-Bold.ttf.TIME_45.pfo
[ 3/15] Arvo-Regular.ttf.DATE_22.pfo: resources/fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf ../../../pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.8.1/Pebble/tools/font/fontgen.py -> build/resources/fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf.DATE_22.pfo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PJ/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.8.1/Pebble/tools/font/fontgen.py", line 4, in <module>
    import freetype
  File "/Users/PJ/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-current/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freetype/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError, 'Freetype library not found'
RuntimeError: Freetype library not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PJ/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.8.1/Pebble/tools/font/fontgen.py", line 4, in <module>
    import freetype
  File "/Users/PJ/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-current/.env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/freetype/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError, 'Freetype library not found'
RuntimeError: Freetype library not found
Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/PJ/Documents/GitHub/simple-for-pebble/build'
Build failed
 -> task in 'Arvo-Bold.ttf.TIME_45.pfo' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 4471793616: Arvo-Bold.ttf.TIME_45.pfo Arvo-Bold.ttf,fontgen.py -> Arvo-Bold.ttf.TIME_45.pfo}
" python '/Users/PJ/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.8.1/Pebble/tools/font/fontgen.py' pfo  45 --tracking -1   --legacy '/Users/PJ/Documents/GitHub/simple-for-pebble/resources/fonts/Arvo-Bold.ttf' '/Users/PJ/Documents/GitHub/simple-for-pebble/build/resources/fonts/Arvo-Bold.ttf.TIME_45.pfo' "
 -> task in 'Arvo-Regular.ttf.DATE_22.pfo' failed (exit status 1): 
    {task 4471793936: Arvo-Regular.ttf.DATE_22.pfo Arvo-Regular.ttf,fontgen.py -> Arvo-Regular.ttf.DATE_22.pfo}
" python '/Users/PJ/pebble-dev/PebbleSDK-2.8.1/Pebble/tools/font/fontgen.py' pfo  22    --legacy '/Users/PJ/Documents/GitHub/simple-for-pebble/resources/fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf' '/Users/PJ/Documents/GitHub/simple-for-pebble/build/resources/fonts/Arvo-Regular.ttf.DATE_22.pfo' "
[ERROR   ] A compilation error occurred
```

Comment: The error in that mess is given on the line that starts with "RuntimeError:".  The error says that the script could not find the Freetype library on your system.  To fix it, I'm going to guess you will have to download and install the Freetype library.

Comment: In the future, please try to make your question title more meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple-for-Pebble uses custom fonts, so you'll need to install Freetype in order for the Pebble SDK to be able to process the TTF files.

There are instructions on how to do this on the Pebble Developer website (https://developer.getpebble.com/sdk/install/mac/#pebble-sdk-fonts-and-freetype), but the quickest way to install it is using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

```
brew install freetype
```